# ReferenceError: Array is not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created the array 'arr' on my browser console. Instead give 'delete arr' to remove my array, I gave it as 'delete Array' because of autofill intelligence. Now the console is running forever with this error message. How to stop this?

[image]

Comment: Clear the `cache`:  Ctrl +F5

Comment: Just to note: `delete` is not for deleting variables... It's for deleting object's properties

Comment: Congratulations, you've just found a practical example of a basic prgramming principle: Shit in, shit out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the `cache`: Ctrl + F5